# Spring Security don't allow resouce

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I have configuration

```
http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/shutdown").permitAll()
                    .and().formLogin().passwordParameter("password").usernameParameter("username")
                    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/authentication.html").permitAll()
                    .and().formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .and().formLogin().failureUrl("/authentication.html")
                    .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/",false);
```

Authentication works perfectly but I don't have access to /shutdown without authentication. What could be the reason of this?

/shutdown - Shutdown hook of spring boot.

Comment: u mean "authentication works perfectly"?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I mean authentication

Comment: well, i see that @Serge already gave you the correct answer that I wanted to write...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned "/**" means any request and only the first pattern that is matched will be used. One thing to note is that you can cleanup your configuration quite a bit. See the cleaner version below:

```
http
   .csrf().disable()
   .authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/shutdown").permitAll()
       .anyRequest().authenticated()
       .and()
   .formLogin()
       .loginPage("/authentication.html")
       .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
       .failureUrl("/authentication.html")
       .permitAll();
```

Highlights of the changes:

- You should not ever need to type http twice. You can do this of course, but it is not required and it saves you typing
- .antMatchers("/**") has an alias of .anyRequest() which reads a lot nicer
- when specifying properties for .formLogin() you only need to specify .formLogin() once. Like, http, you can state it multiple times, but it is a lot more concise not to do this
- defaultSuccessUrl does not need the false parameter (it is the equivalent of omitting the parameter all together). For example, instead of .defaultSuccessUrl("/", false), you can state .defaultSuccessUrl("/"). Furthermore, the default value for .defaultSuccessUrl is already "/". This means you can remove it all together.
- You will notice that I follow an exact formatting for the JavaConfig that is outlined in [this blog](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/spring-security-java-config-preview-readability/)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Is this configuration applies only to spring boot or I can use it in spring security without spring boot?

Comment: It applies to both Spring Boot and Spring Security without Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. Spring tries patterns in sequence and stops at the first that matches. As your first pattern is `/**` it catches all and next patterns are not even analyzed. You should always put the catchall as last pattern :

```
http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/shutdown").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                    .and().formLogin().passwordParameter("password").usernameParameter("username")
                    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/authentication.html").permitAll()
                    .and().formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .and().formLogin().failureUrl("/authentication.html")
                    .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is intentionally designed that way. See the [Actuator endpoints description](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints) in Spring Boot Guide. And for a good reason. It's a bad idea to leave the shutdown hook open without any security. Anyone who knows the url could shutdown your application.

Comment: I agree with you. In my case its just for development issues and it will be disabled soon.